# TinyMCE Could not load emoticons error in window while using emoticons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in my React application. Whenever I am trying to use emojis, it gives me an error in the emoticons popup saying "Could not load emoticons". It was working fine earlier but now I'm getting this error. Any idea how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Please include your code and a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually issue was sometimes the code I was running on editor **init** event would fail causing the emoticons loading to fail as well. No idea how it relates but changing the code in my **init** event fixed the issue.